# using special characters in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, quoted-identifier

I have table as

```
create table loan 
(loan_id varchar2(20),
cust_id varchar2(10),
loan_amt number,
start_date date,
loan_plan varchar2(20),
end_date date,
Credit_bureau_score varchar2(20),
"small char" varchar2(20),
"special_char3^%#$@#^%*&" varchar2(20)
);
```

only the column names are in special charater. 
Now in a procedure i am using 
    select column_name into some_variable from dba_tab_column where table_name='loan'
now I have to pass some_variable to some other procedure but here i am getting error as
**ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [17090], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []**

How can i resolve this.

Comment: In general, you can't do much about ORA-00600. But in this case: why not remove special characters from the column names? :)

Comment: Found some entries for ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [17090], [], on Oracle support. The error is very generic so there is nothing you can do about it. Just stop using these special characters.

Answer (score 4):

ORA-00600 most of the time indicates a bug in Oracle.

You can either file a bug report and hope for a patch or you could simply stop using those characters in the column names.

I would strongly suggest you use the latter approach and remove those special characters. Even if it would through an ORA-00600 I'm sure you hit hit *loads* of problems in the long run because of them.

Comment: That's right. General rule is: NOT to user spaces or spacial characters in places where it asks for trouble (any Oracle object name). You asked for trouble you got it - infamous ORA-00600.